# Why does `echo | xargs > >(cat)` hang on my Mac?

Tags: macos, bash, zsh, xargs

This is reproducible in `zsh` and `bash`.

Confusing me further, `echo | ( xargs; : ) > >(cat)` does not hang. This is also reproducible in `zsh` and `bash`.

If I use GNU's `xargs` as provided by `brew install findutils` it doesn't hang: `echo | gxargs > >(cat)`.

Indeed I haven't found any other program besides my system's `xargs` that behaves this way. I figured there might be something `xargs` is doing with the file descriptors so I tried replacing `xargs` with `bash -c 'kill -9 $$'` or `bash -c 'exec 0<&- 1<&-'` or many other shots in the dark.

I also sought help on `##mac`, `#macosx`, `##linux`, and `#bash` on Freenode but no one there seemed to know what was going on. [I also asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60073720/why-does-echo-xargs-cat-hang-on-my-mac) but it wasn't quite programming-enough.

---

```
> sw_vers | head -n 2
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.2

> zsh --version
zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)

> bash --version | head -n 1
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)

> strings $(which xargs) | grep 'xargs.c'
$FreeBSD: src/usr.bin/xargs/xargs.c,v 1.57 2005/02/27 02:01:31 gad Exp $

> gxargs --version | head -n 1
xargs (GNU findutils) 4.7.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find the source code for my system's `xargs` by running `strings $(which xargs)` and looking for interesting keywords. `PROJECT:shell_cmds-207.40.1` stuck out to me and soon I found the source code for a slightly older version `shell_cmds-203` on [Apple's Open Source site](https://opensource.apple.com/release/macos-10145.html).

I compiled the version of `xargs` in that package with `gcc -g *.c`, ran `echo | ./a.out > >(cat)`, and attached my debugger `lldb` to the `a.out` process. I found out that it was stuck in a call to `waitpid` from `xargs.c:610` ([source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-203/xargs/xargs.c.auto.html)). Excerpt:

```
while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, !waitall && curprocs < maxprocs ?
        WNOHANG : 0)) > 0) {
```

Because `xargs` is a complicated program, I wanted to make a smaller C program that'd reproduce the behavior. Here it is:

```
// tiny.c
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
    int status;
    waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling that with `gcc tiny.c -o tiny` and running `echo | ./tiny > >(cat)` hung just like `xargs`. Indeed, now I could simplify even further, `./tiny > >(cat)` would hang, while `( ./tiny; : ) > >(cat)` would not hang.

*Aside: this tiny program can be compiled on Linux and then you can reproduce this behavior on Linux easily.*

Passing `-1` to `waitpid` will cause it to wait on *any child process*. So that begs the question: **why does `tiny` have a child process in `./tiny > >(cat)` but not `( ./tiny; : ) > >(cat)`?**

I haven't dived into `bash`'s source code, but I have a pretty well-educated guess about what's going on.

First let's dissect the first command: `./tiny > >(cat)`. First `bash` creates a named pipe, and then `fork()-exec()`s `cat` into creation as a child process. Then it sets its own `stdout` to be that same named pipe. Finally `bash` finishes its life by calling `exec()` to transform into `tiny`. Now `tiny` has the same PID and the OS still considers the `cat` process to be its child.

Importantly, the same thing happens with `( ./tiny ) > >(cat)` but it just `exec()`s into bash (parenthesis start a subshell) and then into `tiny`. A key fact seems to be that when `bash` is started with only one command to execute, it doesn't `fork()-exec()` but rather just `exec()`s immediately.

Now let's dissect the second command: `( ./tiny; : ) > >(cat)`. We get the same thing at the start: `fork()-exec()`ing `cat` into existence. Then `bash` `exec()`s into a new `bash` instance. Then it sees it has two commands to execute, so it `fork()-exec()`s `tiny` into existence, and because it forked, this new `tiny` process doesn't have `cat` as a child so it doesn't hang. Then `bash` executes `:` (`:` is a special built-in so there's no exec here, but using a non-built-in would still cause `tiny` to be forked so there still wouldn't be any hanging).